# how to create a density heat mat with x and y coordinate and 2 types

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, density-plot

So I have my coordinate x and y and a variable that class those coordinate as either success or fail. I would like to create ggplot - heat map of those coordinate with both classes on the map.

Also, I created a value "my_colours" so they appeared two different colours in the map

Here is my code so far.

```
tv <- data.frame(
  x = c(61, 81, 4, 56, 46, 8, 61, 51, 82, 57, 79, 58, 53, 38, 70, 75, 50, 82, 40, 36, 68, 28, 87, 38, 67, 82, 74, 28, 28, 54, 56, 61, 69),
  y = c(41, -4, 6, -13, 20, 27, -29, -29, 1, 6, 2, -4, 27, -24, -38, 5, 6, -1, 30, -6, 12, 20, -20, -23, 25, 4, 2, 37, -38, -19, 41, -14, -30),
  type = c("s", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "s", "s", "s", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "s", "s", "s", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "s", "s", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "s", "s", "s", "f"))


my_colours = c("f" = "red", "s" = "green")

ggplot(tv, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  coord_flip()+
  lims(x = c(0, 100), y = c(42.5, -42.5)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill=type), geom = 'polygon', alpha = .4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_colours)
```

The error that I receive is this one

```
Warning messages:
1: stat_contour(): Zero contours were generated 
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

However, within a similar dataset, I have no problem creating the heat map using the same code.

Comment: When the values from my x and y changed I received error message like this. `Warning messages:
1: stat_contour(): Zero contours were generated 
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`

Comment: I'm rerunning your code exactly and don't get warning or error messages. I'm not sure what you think the output should look like?